# WinRar failing to grant adminstrative access to extracted script

Tags: windows-10, winrar

For almost 10 years I have used WinRar to create an SFX archive of scripts that are used to run preventive maintenance on client computers. Some of the scripts make entries to the registry so I've always checked the administrative access box.

After making some minor changes to the scripts (mostly cmd), everything works perfectly including the fact that the scripts run in Administrative windows but, they do not write to the registry.

I've inserted temporary code (fsutil dirty query %SYSTEMDRIVE%) to confirm that the script does have elevated authority so I know that isn't the problem. I updated my WinRar 5.01 to 5.7 thinking that that might be the problem but... no joy.

I'm running Win10 Pro and now the updated WinRar. I've recreated the package multiple times to no avail and the code works perfectly if it's runas admin separately from WinRar.

Any suggestions to resolve this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: When did that "problem" become apparent? What's the actual question? What happens if you run your script? What output is being generated?

Comment: The problem happened this week when I created a new SFX archive that incorporated an updated script designed to write an entry to the registry. It works when run outside of WinRar. The question is what setting could be causing this. I'm using the same ones I've used for years. No error is generated but the write doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

A week ago, I would have argued that the problem I've been seeing was impossible but, that just not the case.
Extensive testing and research has provided no explanation why an SFX WinRar archive with administrative access gives an extracted setup cmd script administrative access without the ability to write to the registry but that is exactly what happens.
I resolved the problem by using the setup script to start a service that then starts what was the original setup script and both the process and the original script works perfectly.